# Is there a way to force HTTP server to send me a specific header via libcurl?

Tags: c, http, libcurl

Specifically `Content-Length`. When i send the HEAD request to my local server, i don't always receive the size of the requested file.
For example, when it's 159 bytes index.php:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2016 11:34:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And 40-something MB random .pdf file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2016 11:34:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20
Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 11:19:59 GMT
ETag: "2807fb2-53ae39413d130"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 41975730
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Can i force it or not?

Comment: `Content-length` is a mandatory header field in `HTTP/1.1` when the length is known.  If you don't receive one, is because `HEAD` request ask for a response with no payload (no content) or because it is not known, and in that case you have to accept `Content-disposition: chunked` (don't know if this is exactly as shown, check rfc) So in the case of HEAD response `Content-length` should be zero (and is not included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Either the size is available – or it is not.

Especially, in the case of php scripts, the content is generated dynamically, and the size is not known beforehand.

Essentially, `HEAD` does the same as `GET`, but omits the payload.

Comment: then why won't server generate content-length header after content is generated by php?

Comment: @KarashevichB. Because the content isn't buffered (again, due to its unknown size). Instead, it is immediately sent over the line, making it impossible to add an additional header.

Comment: `Content-length:` is mandatory when known, and chunked disposition when unknown, in `HTTP/1.1`.  If you don't know, you have to use `content-disposition: chunked` or switch to `HTTP/1.0`